# various way in which window application can send data to web application using cef

Tags: chromium-embedded

How to send context data from wPF application to the WebApplication using CEF? Currently I am sending the data by using the functionality of CEF i.e. by executing Javascript on the brower, serching the control and then binding the value, is there any other way of doing the same?